# How to discover the Unicode codepoint and UTF-8 encoded value of a unknown character?

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding

I'm doing text mining on content that comes from the web. There is a lot of chars that I want to convert to perform better classification (eg.: `&nbsp` to white spaces).

The problem is sometimes I'm getting some unknown chars and I want to discover the Unicode codepoint and UTF-8 representation of it.

**I want to know if there is some online tool that can inform this or a program.**

At the moment, I'm trying to discover a **line-break** that I found, but don't matches the `\n` or `\s` from regex.  In the past time, I had troubles with the &nbsp.

I don't know what is and I want to know if there is a way to discover.

The char appears here, after *personagens*, but is only possible to see viewing the original code without formatation.

`"personagens
"`

Comment: Unicode is a standard; there is no such thing as Unicode representation of a character. There are however, valid Unicode encodings of a character, like UTF-8, UTF-16 encodings to represent a character. You might therefore, want to clarify what you are seeking. Are you looking for Unicode codepoints of a character, or its encoding?

Comment: You might want to check out [this character inspector app](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/09/java-character-inspector-application.html) from [McDowell](http://stackoverflow.com/users/304/mcdowell). although I'm still not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: @Vinnet: I think he's looking for the char that matches a certain escaped expression, e.g. get `"` for the input `&quot;`. And by the way, Renato, it should be `&nbsp;` (with a semicolon).

Comment: @Vinnet Post your comment as an answer. It worked and I discovered the mysterious chars I was searching. It's `\u0020`.

Comment: @Eran The problem I was having it that sometimes appears non-printable chars in the rows in the database because I'm using an external tool to convert from HTML to pure text. What I was searching is a tool that let me discover the code of this non-printable chars. In the truth, was not `&nbsp;` (with semicolon :D), but a `\u00A0`.

Comment: I looked at a hex editor and the result is different. Appears to be a `\u000A`.

Comment: Nothing mysterious here.  A `\u000A` is a linefeed character (LF), and a `\u0020` is a space (SP) character.

Comment: @Stephen Yes, this char are not misterious, but while you have only a visual space, is not so easy to say: "this is a non-breaking whitespace, and not a common whitespace" or "it's a line-feed". This was the intention, a way to discover the char. I used the hex editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments, it appears that you needed to know the Unicode codepoints of certain characters, or their UTF-8 representations.

You can use [the character inspector application](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/09/java-character-inspector-application.html), written by [McDowell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/304/mcdowell), who's one of StackOverflow's users, to determine the Unicode codepoint as well as the UTF-8 representations. You'll need to set the charset as UTF-8 in the application, once you've pasted the contents of the message.

You can also use the `String` class of the Java API to get the raw codepoints of characters in a String, via the [`codePointAt`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt%28int%29) method. Note, that if you convert the `String` to a `char` array, the array will contain UTF-16 encoded characters; while, this is fine if you intend to invoke the [`Character.codePointAt`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#codePointAt%28char%5B%5D,%20int%29) method, you must take care to ensure that you deal with low surrogates.

Answer (score 2):

Run the [uniquote program](http://training.perl.com):

```
$ echo 'bád⁠⁠ƨtüﬀ' | uniquote -x
b\x{E1}d\x{2060}\x{2060}\x{1A8}t\x{FC}\x{FB00}

$ echo 'bád⁠⁠ƨtüﬀ' | uniquote -v
b\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE}d\N{WORD JOINER}\N{WORD JOINER}\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER TONE TWO}t\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS}\N{LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FF}

$ echo 'bád⁠⁠ƨtüﬀ' | uniquote --html
b&#225;d&#8288;&#8288;&#424;t&#252;&#64256;
```

You don’t need to use `echo`; you can just cut and paste, then hit ^D when you’re done:

```
$ uniquote -v -
'bád⁠⁠ƨtüﬀ'
^D
'b\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE}d\N{WORD JOINER}\N{WORD JOINER}\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER TONE TWO}t\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS}\N{LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FF}'
```